# RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L] (URL書き換え処理) について

Tags: apache, 正規表現, .htaccess

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]

◇◇◇◇にアクセスがあったら、◆◆◆◆に404Not Foundを行う処理。

ですが、

```
^は行頭、
*は0回以上の繰り返し(最長一致数量子)、
.は改行以外のあらゆる一文字を表す事ができ、
$は行末
```

RewriteRuleで使うフラグ

```
R:指定したURLにリダイレクトする。【例】R=301で301リダイレクト(redirect)
L:ここでURL書き換え処理を中止し、それ以降の書き換えはしないようにする(last)
```

(1)この^.*$という表現は◇◇◇◇の部分に相当すると思いますが、どこにアクセスするのでしょうか。

(2)^.*$と[R=404,L]の間にある"-"は何を表しているのでしょうか。◆◆◆◆を表しているのでしょうか。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRuleの詳細は以下を参照してください。
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html

RewriteRuleのシンタックスは上記URLにもありますが、以下の通りです。

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

RewriteRuleはリクエストされてきたURLがpatternにマッチしたとき、Substitutionに従ってリクエストされたURLを書き換え、再度サーバーにURLを解釈させます。
この時、パターンAをBに書き換えるルールと、パターンBをAに書き換えるというルールを同時に作ってしまうとループして500エラーが発生します。

> (1)この^.*$という表現は◇◇◇◇の部分に相当すると思いますが、どこにアクセスするのでしょうか。

リクエストされたパス全体を示しています。

> (2)^.*$と[R=404,L]の間にある"-"は何を表しているのでしょうか。◆◆◆◆を表しているのでしょうか。

これは私も理解せずに使っていたのですが、上記URL内で

> - (dash) A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a
>     flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

と定義されています。
要するに何も置換を行わないということです。

Comment: 参照先URLが誤っていたのと、引用をフランス語でしてしまっていたので英語に変更しました

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
> ```

Webサーバーへアクセスがあったらパス部の内容に依らず常に `404 Not Found` のレスポンスを返す。

です。